# Firebug lite in browser mode IE7 deosn't show

Tags: internet-explorer, firebug-lite

Does anyone know a work around without having to install virtual machines to get the firebug console to display in Ie7 browser mode (F12) in IE please? It displays fine in modes IE8 and IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something and thought it may be useful for others here.

Basically call the js script directly and place it in the actaual site /page itself you want to test instead of clicking the bookmarklet. It's alot less buggy too in the other browser modes than the bookmarklet allowed for.

```
<script src='http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js'></script>
```